# Set a div's height to the remaining height in the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've found multiple answers on this question, but they all do not seem to work, especially the CSS way. I've moved to the jQuery method, however, it doesn't work neither.

I've got two divs at the moment: A header and a content div. The header has a height of 120px, I'd like the content div to be located below the header and have the remaining height of the screen. I've found multiple answers, I've tried to implent those methods, however, it still didn't work. So that's why I'm asking this question.

Here is my current code:

```
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var one = $('#header').height(),
    two = parseInt($(window).height() - one);
    $('#border').height(two)
</script>

<div class="header" id="one">hi</div>
<div class="border" id="two">hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br><div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    background-image:url(../images/bg.png);
    background-repeat:repeat;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    height: 100%;
}

.header
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 120px;
    background-color: black;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px #000000;
}

.border
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 25%;
    z-index:0;
    top: 120px;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    padding: 5px;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my knowledge you can achieve this by

**pure `css` using `position:absolute`.**

**and with the help of jQuery**

I've solve your problem by both ways check out below solutions

I've checked and find some bugs in your code

**1. in your `html` code you forget to close your `<div id="two">`.**
**2. In your `css` code there you applied `height:100%` to your class which are reflecting.**
**3. In your `jQuery` code you are trying to set height but with wrong selectors. That's why your code is not working**

so i've fixed it in my case you have to change in your css code, html code and jquery code
check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/yNg95/2/

**here is Html**

```
<div class="header" id="one">hi</div>
<div class="border" id="two">
    hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>
</div>
```

**here is css code**

```
*{margin:0; padding:0;}
body {
    background-image:url(../images/bg.png);
    background-repeat:repeat;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.header{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right:0;
    height: 120px;
    background-color: black;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px #000000;
}

.border{
    position: absolute;
    left: 25%;
    z-index:0;
    width: 50%;
    top:120px;
    /*height: 100%;*/
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    padding: 5px;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

**here is jquery code**

```
var one, two;
    one = $('.header').outerHeight(true);
    two = $(window).height() - one;
    console.log(one, two)
    $('#two').css({height : two})
```

**here is the fiddle for another option only by pure `css`**

http://jsfiddle.net/sarfarazdesigner/neR4U/

Comment: It indeed looks like your code should work. I must be doing something utterly wrong. It looks like I'm not installing jQuery properly (<html>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="includes/index.css" type="text/css">
 <head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <script>
 var one, two;
    one = $('.header').outerHeight(true);
    two = $(window).height() - one;
 console.log(one, two)
    $('#two').css({height : two})
 </script>
 <body>

 </body>
</html>)

Comment: @stefan1294 you can match your code to mine code then you understand what's wrong with your code. i've updated both answer take a look

Comment: Thank you. Apparently I forgot to load the function when the page was loaded. I added an event and it works now.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<div class="header" id="one">hi</div>
<div class='border' scrolling="auto" style="width: 100%;height:100%;position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;right:0px;bottom:0px" height="100%" width="100%" id="two">
```

Comment: If I set it's height to 100%, I will be able to scroll down in the page as well, not just the div. The div didn't resize, the height is just 100% now.

Answer (score 0):

How about if you just add `height: 100%;` to the "border" class?

http://jsfiddle.net/yNg95/1/

Comment: If I set it's height to 100%, I will be able to scroll down in the page as well, not just the div. The div didn't resize, the height is just 100% now.

Comment: This is because you have a header div on top. Edited my answer. Check it.

Answer (score 0):

Add `height: 78%;` to your border css, and add `height: 20%;` to your header css. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dLhxD/)